# Pandas resample based on higher resolution data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two time-series one on 30 min resolution and one on 15 minute resolution **A** and **B** as shown under. I would like to Upsample **A** to a 15 minute resolution using **B** to scale the values for the given interval. So for the first value it would be:

```
B['final']['01/11/2017  07:30:00'] =  77.0*29.7/(29.7+12.67)
```

**A['irrad']**

```
2017-11-01 07:30:00     77.0
2017-11-01 08:00:00    214.0
2017-11-01 08:30:00    470.0
2017-11-01 09:00:00    714.0
```

**B['util']**

```
2017-11-01 07:15:00     12.67
2017-11-01 07:30:00     29.70
2017-11-01 07:45:00     46.80
2017-11-01 08:00:00     74.07
2017-11-01 08:15:00    166.27
2017-11-01 08:30:00    256.50
2017-11-01 08:45:00    271.70
2017-11-01 09:00:00    354.33
```

So the final series would be

**B['final']**

```
01/11/2017 07:30    54.0
01/11/2017 07:45    82.9
01/11/2017 08:00    131.1
01/11/2017 08:15    184.8
01/11/2017 08:30    285.2
```

I was looking into Pandas resample or merge functions but could see this being possible. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be useful to implement functions to convert the date and times to numbers and viceversa (in your desided format(s)). Then the operation would become trivial.

Comment: How did you get to these values, say 23 for the first one? I don't see how it matches your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you upsample, then left-merge to util:

```
A.index = pd.to_datetime(A.index)
B.index = pd.to_datetime(B.index)
merged = pd.merge(B, A.resample('15s').ffill(), left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
>>> merged

util    irrad
index       
2017-11-01 07:15:00 12.67   NaN
2017-11-01 07:30:00 29.70   77.0
2017-11-01 07:45:00 46.80   77.0
2017-11-01 08:00:00 74.07   214.0
2017-11-01 08:15:00 166.27  214.0
2017-11-01 08:30:00 256.50  470.0
2017-11-01 08:45:00 271.70  470.0
2017-11-01 09:00:00 354.33  714.0
```

Now you can use

```
>>> merged.irrad * merged.util / (merged.util + merged.util.shift(-1))
index
2017-11-01 07:15:00           NaN
2017-11-01 07:30:00     29.894118
2017-11-01 07:45:00     29.813850
2017-11-01 08:00:00     65.952318
2017-11-01 08:15:00     84.163446
2017-11-01 08:30:00    228.237410
2017-11-01 08:45:00    203.982237
2017-11-01 09:00:00           NaN
dtype: float64
```

Note that this isn't what you specified in your question. Feel free to clarify how you got to your final results.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. Not exactly the answer I wanted mostly because the formula I posted is wrong. I need the value to be scaled based on the values in the current 30 min interval. So `(merged.util + merged.util.shift(-1))` is not correct. Instead I had to resample  **B** to 30 minutes and take the sum. This worked out fine.

Comment: Glad it helped out somewhat :-)